# "Es schadet einem nicht." What is the meaning of "einem" here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, dative, objects

I saw it on [link to youtube, at 1:18](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4vmlFAti_Ogv) the following sentence:

> Es schadet einem nicht

According to my understanding, "es schadet nicht" simply means "it doesn't hurt". But what is the meaning if "einem" is added? Does it mean: "it doesn't hurt, not even one"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perhaps you know *man*, as in: *Man kann hier schwimmen / One/You can swim here.* This is just a way to generically refer to unspecified people.

But *man* can only be used when it is the subject of a sentence (and hence only in the nominative case). However, for the accusative and the dative case, a replacement exists: the masculine form of *einer* (singular), i.e. *einen* in the accusative and *einem* in the dative case. (There is no alternative for the genitive case.)

This is what you are looking at here. *Es schadet einem nicht* simply means that it doesn't hurt one/you. An example with the accusative would be *Ein Rechtsstreit kann einen viel Geld kosten* (a court proceeding can cost you a lot of money).

Answer (score 4):

> Es schadet **einem** nicht.

*It doesn't hurt **one**.*

The verb *schaden* has a "built-in accusative object" corresponding to the noun *der Schaden* (damage). It goes with a **dative object** because of that. This *einem* is the **receiver of the damage** expressed by the verb *schaden*.

> Rauchen schadet **der Gesundheit**

If it's clear from context, you can leave out the receiver.

> Rauchen schadet.
>
> Es schadet nicht.

This shows *einem* in the original sentence is put in to focus on the receiver **one**.

Comment: "It doesn't hurt one" is not exactly wrong, but it is something that no English speaker would ever say. In ordinary English one says "It doesn't hurt you".

Comment: Yes. But the German equivalent of *It doesn't hurt you.* is *Es schadet **dir** nicht.* German speakers like that *explicit unpersonal you* — *einer/eine/eins* and *man* — very much. It's sometimes expressed by **one** in English too: *One cannot help it.* That's why I put it in.

Answer (score 2):

My answer differs slightly from the other two answers. In this context, I believe "einem" would mean "*any*one."

So Es schadet einem nicht means, "It doesn't hurt anyone."