# What is the case of "einem" in this context?

Tags: grammatical-case, pronoun, dative, declension-table

> Man hat so Dinge im Kopf, die **einem wichtig** vorkommen. Aber was im
>   Endeffekt das Wichtigste ist, finde ich interessant zu sehen.

I can't analyze the case of "einem wichtig" in the above sentence. I take *die wichtig vorkommen* as a predicative sentence in the following form if we want to say in English:

> They appear to be important.

And in German:

> Sie vorkommen wichtig.

But then I cannot understand why "wichtig" should get "einem".

So I then thought maybe "einem" is not an article for "wichtig" but means something like "at first look" or alike, but couldn't find anything about it.

Comment: @Arsak corrected!

Comment: As for the case, see Indefinite article declension table.It's not even big! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_declension#Indefinite_article  As for the meaning, see the already answered question https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/46818/es-schadet-einem-nicht-what-is-the-meaning-of-einem-here

Comment: _"Sie vorkommen wichtig."_ That's not even remotely valid German (and even your English sentence is wrong).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *einem* could be translated into English as *to you* (or a bit longer but closer to the original meaning: *to the person making the observation*).

So

> Man hat so Dinge im Kopf, die einem wichtig vorkommen.

translates to

> You have items in your mind that appear to be important to you

or a bit further away from literal translation but less ambiguous

> You have items in your mind that you consider important.

Comment: May be even better expressed as "to one" - quite literally derived from a number just like "ein" is.

Answer (score 3):

The Wiktionary entry for *[vorkommen](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/vorkommen)* lists characteristic word combinations. If *vorkommen* is used with the meaning *[4] auf jemanden in einer Weise wirken*, it is often used as:

> [4] jemandem kommt etwas vor wie/als

where *jemandem* is in dative case.

Your example sentence follows this structure: *einem* is not used as an article, but as a **pronoun** (in dative case) that replaces *jemandem*, see this [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ein_Pronomen) entry for more examples.